# Phaser: camera follow not working (js)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm a fairly new JavaScript programmer and having some trouble making a game.

Currently I have a plane game on a scrolling background that won't follow the plane as it flies in the sky. The game stays in the top left 800x600 resolution of the screen.

Here is the code:
(I haven't included the update function but this has a game.camera.follow(plane) line and functions to move the plane using arrow keys.

```
//Set window
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, '', { preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update,
    render: render });

function preload() {

    ///Load assets
    game.load.image('sky', 'assets/backplate2.png');
    game.load.image('plane', 'assets/plane.png');
    game.load.image('banner', 'assets/screenbanner.png');

}

//Variables
var plane;
var backgrounda = 0.1;
var backgroundv = 2;
var width;
var height;
var energy = 0;
var scoreText;
var cursors;

function create() {
    //creates sprites
    sky = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 1920, 1080, 'sky');
    //sky = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky');
    banner = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'banner');
    plane = game.add.sprite(500, 500, 'plane');
    scoreText = game.add.text(16, 16, 'Energy:  0 J', {fontSize: '32px',
        fill: '#229'});

    game.physics.arcade.setBounds(0, 70, 1920, 1040);
    game.camera.tilePosition

    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.arcade);

    game.physics.arcade.enable(plane);

    banner.scale.setTo(0.42, 0.42);
    plane.scale.setTo(0.1, 0.1);
    plane.body.gravity.y = 400;
    plane.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    game.camera.follow(plane);

}
```

Comment: setting up a fiddle or pen, will be quite useful

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem `game.world.setBounds(0, 70, 1920, 1040);`

I think you also have a typo or something?    `game.camera.tilePosition`